# SilverStripe hardcode permission setting EDIT_SITECONFIG

Tags: php, silverstripe

There is a specific `PermissionCode` that's not granted to `ContentAuthor` by default. It's about Permission code `EDIT_SITECONFIG` (enables *Content Authors* to view and edit "Settings" section).

This permission can be granted to `roles` in:
`Security > Groups > Content Authors > Permissions` > **Manage site configuration**

[image: Site config permission]

How can you force this permission to be granted to `ContentAuthors` by default?

Comment: How, any groups are you creating? Surely you can add users to more than one group, thus have all the necessary people in a group with the required permissions. Then it wouldn't matter what the default is.

Comment: That would work as well. But I'm trying to create a more automated solution for each SilverStripe installation, hence my preference for hardcoding this in a module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can add an extension to the `Group` class that calls `requireDefaultRecords` to modify this variable.

**mysite/code/extensions/CustomGroup.php**

```
class CustomGroup extends DataExtension {

    public function requireDefaultRecords() {
        parent::requireDefaultRecords();

        $contentAuthorGroup = Group::get()->filter('Code', 'content-authors')->first();
        if ($contentAuthorGroup) {
            Permission::grant($contentAuthorGroup->ID, 'EDIT_SITECONFIG');
        }
    }
}
```

We enable our `Group` extension in our `config.yml` file.

**mysite/_config/config.yml**

```
Group:
  extensions:
    - CustomGroup
```

One thing to note with this solution is it will update the `EDIT_SITECONFIG` permission setting every time `dev/build` is called. This means if this permission is switched off through the CMS it will be switched back on the next time `dev/build` is called.

An alternative is to create the content author group on the first database build. This will only set `EDIT_SITECONFIG` once, allowing it to be overwritten through the CMS.

```
class CustomGroup extends DataExtension {

    public function requireDefaultRecords() {

        // Add default author group if no other group exists
        $allGroups = Group::get();
        if (!$allGroups->count()) {
            $authorGroup = new Group();
            $authorGroup->Code = 'content-authors';
            $authorGroup->Title = _t('Group.DefaultGroupTitleContentAuthors', 'Content Authors');
            $authorGroup->Sort = 1;
            $authorGroup->write();
            Permission::grant($authorGroup->ID, 'CMS_ACCESS_CMSMain');
            Permission::grant($authorGroup->ID, 'CMS_ACCESS_AssetAdmin');
            Permission::grant($authorGroup->ID, 'CMS_ACCESS_ReportAdmin');
            Permission::grant($authorGroup->ID, 'SITETREE_REORGANISE');
            Permission::grant($authorGroup->ID, 'EDIT_SITECONFIG');
        }

        parent::requireDefaultRecords();
    }
}
```

Comment: Magnificent. First method works exactly as you described. Second method seems better but that one basically only works by including it in the installation files right?

Comment: That's right. The second method will only work on the initial database build during site installation.

Comment: are you sure about the first method "toggling" between on and off? I just tested it and it seems to stay `true` after each dev/build